# My simulator crashes when I try to terminate my app from the recent-apps bar

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, home-button

My simulator crashes when I try to terminate my app from the recent-apps bar.

When I hit the home button and then my app, the app goes back to where it was, just like it should.

But when i hit the home button, and then the home button twice, and then holding my app and press the (-). The simulator goes in the background and xcode says it crashes. When I hit my app on the simulator now, the simulators screen goes black and won't load anything, and xcode is coming up with a crash message again.. and the simulator is frozen on the black screen...

What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Nothing to worry about. You have to quit debugging session before trying this out.

Comment: You simply click 'stop' button (black square) in XCode. Yes, that will kill your app but you can start it again from simulator (not XCode) and from then on everything should work normally.

Comment: Oh it is working :) Thank you very much!! :D I'm still learning ;)

Comment: Keep on the good work! :D And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing to worry about. This is a normal *feature* of XCode debugging session.

Make sure you stop the debugging session in XCode (hitting the stop - black square - button) and run your application again directly from simulator (not from XCode). It should work now.

Comment: Sorry for popping up an old thread, but can you explain the reason why this happens, because it's like a 50/50 chance. Thanks.

Comment: No problem: closing an app from the "recent-apps" bar actually "kills" the app - for debugger this looks as if your app crashed - since it is not stopped trough "normal" procedure (hitting home button).